# Special characters in Response.RedirectPermanent

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, redirect, response.redirect

I was redirecting to a URL which has some German special characters in it like: ü .

Although in the Firefox this special character remains as it is: ü, but in IE & Chrome it is being changed to : %c3%bc .

How can i prevent this to happen in IE & chrome? 
I was using Response.RedirectPermanent() .

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conversion does not change anything. On reqest it will be converted back. This conversion happened because chars in URL is limited. For more information look at http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm